# How can I make tar read input from stdin?

Tags: tar, input

I need to use `tar` in a pipeline inside a shell script to archive and compress some files.

After having read the [manpage for `tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tar.1.html) I was able to make `tar` output to `stdout` by running it along with the `-O` argument, but I wasn't able to find out how to make it input from `stdin`. Since many commands read from `stdin` if no other input it's specified, I tried:

```bsh
pv ~/foo | tar c -O ~/foo.tar
```

but that didn't work:

```bsh
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive

Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

How can I make `tar` read input from `stdin`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597875/how-can-i-build-a-tar-from-stdin

Comment: If you want to display progress, you might want to do the reverse: `tar c ~/foo | pv > foo.tar`

Comment: @zhongfu Thanks, but `pv` was there because I wanted to see the progress while piping `dd` output in `tar`, as you can deduce from my later [follow-up question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/587081/how-can-i-archive-dds-output-directly-possibly-without-using-any-compression)

Comment: I didn't really get the point of archiving a disk image instead of storing it as is as it's quite pointless, but what I wanted to say was basically covered by @DavidFoerster's answer at that question, so yeah

Comment: @zhongfu I agree with you that in most cases that's plain unuseful, but in that case I wanted to backup also single folders in the same backup file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `-O` with `c` is ignored, since no files are *extracted*. You'll get the same result either way:

```
$ tar c -O foo | tar t
foo
$ tar c foo | tar t  
foo
```

Which is why I find your error surprising, since `tar` is no coward if you specify a path.

`tar` *cannot* read in file data from stdin for creating an archive, since then `tar` will have no way of knowing what a file is - where one begins or ends, what its path and metadata is.

Answer (score 0):

This Python script from my [Unix.StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214586/119298) appends stdin to a tar file, giving it an arbitrary name, using **Python's tarfile** library. It seeks back in the tar to rewrite the header with the right size at eof. The usage would be:

```
cat foo | tarappend -t mytar -f foo
tar tvf mytar
```

Here's the `tarappend` python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# concat stdin to end of tar file, with given name. meuh on stackexchange
# $Id: tarappend,v 1.3 2015/07/08 11:31:18 meuh $

import sys, os, tarfile, time, copy
from optparse import OptionParser
try:
    import grp, pwd
except ImportError:
    grp = pwd = None

usage = """%prog: ... | %prog -t tarfile -f filename
Appends stdin to tarfile under the given arbitrary filename.
tarfile is created if it does not exist.\
"""

def doargs():
    parser = OptionParser(usage=usage)
    parser.add_option("-f", "--filename", help="filename to use")
    parser.add_option("-t", "--tarfile", help="existing tar archive")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if options.filename is None or options.tarfile is None:
        parser.error("need filename and tarfile")
    if len(args):
        parser.error("unknown args: "+" ".join(args))
    return options

def copygetlen(fsrc, fdst):
    """copy data from file-like object fsrc to file-like object fdst. return len"""
    totlen = 0
    while 1:
        buf = fsrc.read(16*1024)
        if not buf:
            return totlen
        fdst.write(buf)
        totlen += len(buf)

class TarFileStdin(tarfile.TarFile):
    def addstdin(self, tarinfo, fileobj):
        """Add stdin to archive. based on addfile() """
        self._check("aw")
        tarinfo = copy.copy(tarinfo)
        buf = tarinfo.tobuf(self.format, self.encoding, self.errors)
        bufoffset = self.offset
        self.fileobj.write(buf)
        self.offset += len(buf)

        tarinfo.size = copygetlen(fileobj, self.fileobj)
        blocks, remainder = divmod(tarinfo.size, tarfile.BLOCKSIZE)
        if remainder > 0:
            self.fileobj.write(tarfile.NUL * (tarfile.BLOCKSIZE - remainder))
            blocks += 1
        self.offset += blocks * tarfile.BLOCKSIZE
        # rewrite header with correct size
        buf = tarinfo.tobuf(self.format, self.encoding, self.errors)
        self.fileobj.seek(bufoffset)
        self.fileobj.write(buf)
        self.fileobj.seek(self.offset)
        self.members.append(tarinfo)

class TarInfoStdin(tarfile.TarInfo):
    def __init__(self, name):
        if len(name)>100:
            raise ValueError(name+": filename too long")
        if name.endswith("/"):
            raise ValueError(name+": is a directory name")
        tarfile.TarInfo.__init__(self, name)
        self.size = 99
        self.uid = os.getuid()
        self.gid = os.getgid()
        self.mtime = time.time()
        if pwd:
            self.uname = pwd.getpwuid(self.uid)[0]
            self.gname = grp.getgrgid(self.gid)[0]

def run(tarfilename, newfilename):
    tar = TarFileStdin.open(tarfilename, 'a')
    tarinfo = TarInfoStdin(newfilename)
    tar.addstdin(tarinfo, sys.stdin)
    tar.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = doargs()
    run(options.tarfile, options.filename)
```