# Is it possible to convert 7z to tar directly?

Tags: tar, 7zip

I have a .7z file containing ~360,000 images in multiple directories. I'd like to convert it to a .tar so that I can open it in another computer. Is there a better way than extracting it to files and compressing them again? Is it possible to do the conversion directly?

Comment: What's preventing you from opening the `.7z` file on another computer?

Comment: I don't have admin rights on the destination to install 7z. I know I can install from source etc...

Comment: There's various web services that offer it.. e.g. https://www.ezyzip.com/convert-7z-to-tar.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not too hard to write something to do the job. Here's an example Perl script (requires the module [Archive::Libarchive::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Libarchive::XS)).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Libarchive::XS qw(:all);

die "Usage: $0 in.7z out.tar" unless @ARGV == 2;
my ($infile, $outfile) = @ARGV;

my $in = archive_read_new();
archive_read_support_filter_none($in);
archive_read_support_format_7zip($in);

archive_read_open_filename($in, $infile, 10240) == ARCHIVE_OK
  or die "Error opening $infile: ", archive_error_string($in);

my $out = archive_write_new();
archive_write_set_format_ustar($out);
archive_write_open_filename($out, $outfile) == ARCHIVE_OK
  or die "Error opening $outfile: ", archive_error_string($out);

while (archive_read_next_header($in, my $entry) == ARCHIVE_OK) {
  archive_write_header($out, $entry) == ARCHIVE_OK
    or die archive_error_string($out);
  while (1) {
    my $size = archive_read_data($in, my $buff, 65536);
    die archive_error_string($in) if $size < 0; 
    last if $size == 0;
    archive_write_data($out, $buff) >= 0
      or die archive_error_string($out);
  }
} 

archive_read_free($in);
archive_write_close($out);
archive_write_free($out);
```

If you wanted a tar.gz / tar.bz2 / tar.xz archive, add the line `archive_write_add_filter_gzip($out);` or `archive_write_add_filter_bzip2($out);` or `archive_tar_add_filter_xz($out);` after the `archive_write_set_format` line.

This uses no temporary disk space (just the space for the output tar file) and very little RAM (just a few MB for perl, but it works with the files a block at a time, so it's not a problem if your files are bigger than your RAM).

Answer (score 15):

`.7z` archives are archives often compressed with some kind of algorithm, while `.tar` archives are just archives.

They differ in their scope, and in most cases a conversion would require an optional decompression always followed by an extraction of the source archive. Even if a `.7z` archive wouldn't use any compression it would still require an extraction.

That being said, If you meant to [decompress] / extract / rearchive the source archive at once, the answer is you can't, at least not using Ubuntu's default tools because [`tar` can't read from `stdin`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587013/how-can-i-make-tar-read-input-from-stdin), so you can't pipe `7z` and `tar`. Anyway it's very easy to automate everything in a single command:

```
mkdir tmp && 7z x <path_to_source_archive> -otmp && tar cf archive.tar tmp && rm -rf tmp
```

<sub>* <path_to_archive> = path to the source `.7z` archive</sub>

Also the time required for the source archive's files to be written to the disk and for the extracted files to be read in order to [decompress] / extract / rearchive the source archive in two steps is a bottleneck for the whole task *mostly* (altough not only) because of a potential disk's low I/O speed, so a partial solution would be to store the temporary files to a ramdisk in order to almost void the overall bottleneck:

1. Create the mount point for the ramdisk's filesystem: `sudo mkdir /mnt/tmpfs`
2. Mount the ramdisk's filesystem: `sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=<tmpfs_size> tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk`<sub>* <tmpfs_size> = size of the filesystem in bytes * 10<sup>3</sup> (1, 1K, 1M, 1G, ...)</sub>
3. Run `mkdir /mnt/tmpfs/tmp && 7z x <path_to_source_archive> -o/mnt/tmpfs/tmp && tar cf archive.tar /mnt/tmpfs/tmp && rm -rf /mnt/tmpfs/tmp`<sub>* <path_to_archive> = path to the source `.7z` archive</sub>
4. Unmount the ramdisk's filesystem: `sudo umount`
5. Remove the mount point for the ramdisk's filesystem: `sudo rmdir /mnt/tmpfs`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22992/discussion-on-answer-by-kos-is-it-possible-to-convert-7z-to-tar-directly).